# pythonの変数や関数の型付けを自動化することは可能か？

Tags: python, vscode

## 状況

例えば以下のような`sqlalchemy`の`create_engine`を呼び出し、`Engine`オブジェクトを返す関数があります。

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def get_engine():
    connection_config = {
        'user': 'USER',
        'password': '********',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 3306,
        'database': 'SOME_DB'
    }
    return create_engine('mysql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(**connection_config))
```

ここで私は`get_engine()`関数の戻り値の型を付けたいと考えました。

## 型を付けるのが大変

しかし、それを行うためには以下のような面倒な工程が必要です。

1. `create_engine()`のドキュメントを見る
2. `create_engine()`は`Engine`オブジェクトを返すことが判明
3. `Engine`オブジェクトはどうすればインポート方法を調べる
4. `Engine`オブジェクトは`from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine`でインポートできることが判明
5. `Engine`オブジェクトをインポートし、`get_engine()`関数に戻り値を書き込む

これらの工程を終え、下記のように型付けを行うことができました。

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine

def get_engine() -> Engine:
    connection_config = {
        'user': 'USER',
        'password': '********',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 3306,
        'database': 'SOME_DB'
    }
    return create_engine('mysql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(**connection_config)
```

しかしプログラムを行っていると関数の数は増えるばかりで、関数を定義するごとに型を調べるのは労力がかかりすぎます。

## 疑問

vscodeのプラグインや何らかのIDE、あるいはツールなどで自動的に`from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine`のインポートを行い、`get_connection()`に`Engine`型を付けることはできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

## 型付けを自動化することは可能か？

はい、可能です。 [Instagram/MonkeyType](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType) や [dropbox/pyannotate](https://github.com/dropbox/pyannotate) のようなツールが存在します。

> Example Say some/module.py originally contains:
>
> ```py
> def add(a, b):
>     return a + b
> ```
>
> And myscript.py contains:
>
> ```py
> from some.module import add
>
> add(1, 2)
> ```
>
> Now we want to infer the type annotation of add in some/module.py by
> running myscript.py with MonkeyType. One way is to run:
>
> `$ monkeytype run myscript.py`
>
> By default, this will dump call traces into a SQLite database in the
> file monkeytype.sqlite3 in the current working directory. You can then
> use the monkeytype command to generate a stub file for a module, or
> apply the type annotations directly to your code.
>
> Running monkeytype stub some.module will output a stub:
>
> ```py
> def add(a: int, b: int) -> int: ...
> ```
>
> Running monkeytype
> apply some.module will modify some/module.py to:
>
> ```py
> def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
>     return a + b
> ```
>
> [GitHub - Instagram/MonkeyType: A Python library that generates static type annotations by collecting runtime types](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType)

## 型を付けるのは大変なのか？

記述では、次のように書いてあります：

> しかし、それを行うためには以下のような面倒な工程が必要です。
>
> - create_engine()のドキュメントを見る
> - create_engine()はEngineオブジェクトを返すことが判明
> - Engineオブジェクトはどうすればインポート方法を調べる
> - Engineオブジェクトはfrom sqlalchemy.engine import Engineでインポートできることが判明
> - Engineオブジェクトをインポートし、get_engine()関数に戻り値を書き込む

しかし、これは別に面倒でもないと思います。
質問の冒頭にある「 `sqlalchemy` の `create_engine` を呼び出し、 `Engine` オブジェクトを返す `get_engine` 関数」は、そもそも`create_engine` のドキュメントを読まないと（＝ どのような引数を必要とし、何を行い、どのような値を返すのか）わからないですし、そうでなければこの `get_engine` 関数が返した値（ `Engine` ）が何なのか、どう使えばいいのか分からないと思います。